# Proc sql - Group by aggregate function from subquery in main query

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I two data sets containing millions of rows. Table1 contains two different ID numbers, ID1 and ID2. It also contains a variable explaining which group (variable y1) a certain ID belongs to.

The second table (Table2) contains two variables from the first table and an additional one.

I want to join the two tables together but before the join, I want table1 to only contain information grouped by ID1 and also for it to give me information which group an ID belongs to.

I could do this in two Proc Sql stages where I first create a table on table1 where I group by ID1 and then create another step where I merge it onto table2. However this is rather inefficient as my tables contain so many rows and I would therefore like to do it in one run. Hence I have instead created a subquery that does what I want. My problem is that I get the error that I can't group by the variable "WhichGroup" from my subquery as it stems from an aggregate function. I'm wondering if there is some good workaround to what I want to achieve?

Many thanks in advance!

Example code:

```
data table1;
input ID1 $ ID2 $ x1 2. y1 $;
datalines;
1 p1 10 Group1
1 p2 20 Group2
2 p3 50 Group1
;
run;

data table2;
input ID1 $ x1 x2;
datalines;
1 10 500
1 20 600
2 50 700
;
run;


Proc sql;
    Create table Test
      as select
        t1.WhichGroup
        ,sum(t1.Sum_x1) as Sum_x1
        ,sum(t2.x2) as Sum_x2
          from (select 
                    a.ID1
                    ,case when max(case when a.y1 = 'Group1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'Group2'
                          when max(case when a.y1 = 'Group2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'Group1'
                          else 'Both' end as WhichGroup
                    ,Sum(a.x1) as Sum_x1
                  from work.table1  as a
                 group by 1
                ) as t1
            left join 
               work.table2   as t2
        on t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
    Group by 1;
Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

**- Answering my own question -**

I am not sure why this is happening but I have encountered a very interest phenomenon and potentially a bug in SAS.

It appears that the whole reason the query doesn't work is because SAS does not understand the group by statement if it is given in digits rather than explicitly stating the variable name you want to group by. Potentially SAS gets lost in the column order?

Has anyone else encountered such a phenomenon before in SAS?

Hence the query works if the following code is used:

```
Proc sql;
    Create table Test
      as select
        t1.WhichGroup
        ,sum(t1.Sum_x1) as sum_x1
        ,sum(t2.x2) as Sum_x2
          from (select 
                    a.ID1
                    ,case when max(case when a.y1 = 'Group1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'Group2'
                          when max(case when a.y1 = 'Group2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'Group1'
                          else 'Both' end as WhichGroup
                    ,Sum(a.x1) as Sum_x1
                  from work.table1  as a
                 group by 1
                ) as t1
            left join 
               work.table2   as t2
        on t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
    Group by WhichGroup;
Quit;
```